# How can I add a new view to my Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Where is the best place to add a new `view` to a Rails app?
I have three main controllers and then the `Application` controller. I folders in views for the three controllers. I want to add a homepage view to my application, separated from the other views. Where would be the best place to add it? Should I make a new folder in views and add a homepage there? Can I add it as part of the `application` controller?

Comment: What I would recommend is use the Rails generators to help set this up.  This will help you.  something like `rails g controller Pages home` for example.  This will create a `PagesController`  with a `home` action and set up the view template for you and all that.  To serve up a new view you need the view file and controller method to handle it, but if you are new to rails this is the fastest way to get it set up until you understand the configuration a little more.

Comment: So I was considering that but is that the only way to create a new view? Can not I utilize the application controller for a view of my landing page? I didn't want to make a whole new controller just for one page. Is it completely okay to do that?

Comment: You wouldn't use the application controller for this.  You would either add it to a different controller, or use a new one.  It depends, is this method unrelated to the other controllers?  If so I would say it is not only o.k., but expected to be put into its own thing instead of just tacked into a controller where it does not belong.  But it depends on your application's structure which I do not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have Rails work consistently and easily, it's best to follow the Rails conventions. So, the views for a particular controller would go into the `app/views` directory, in a subdirectory named for the particular controller. So, the view for your `pages_controller` would go into `app/views/pages` - and you'd have a view named for each relevant action in your controller (`show.html.erb`, for example).

Generally, Rails operates by "convention over configuration". So, if you follow the conventions, you'll find everything works nice and smooth. If you try to create your own conventions, at some point it will bite you and things will stop working.

So, the basic question is: which controller will render your new home-page view? I'm guessing probably `static_pages_controller` or similar. In which case, the view would go into `app/views/static_pages`.

If you don't have a controller then Rails won't render the view at all.

Comment: Thank you! What else can I put in the static pages? If I have users in the application and each user has a "profile" page, should that page still exist in the users' views? And if I want something less specific to the controller like a Help page I add it to the static pages views?

Comment: "Profile" is almost certainly a User view, yes (it's basically showing information from the User table). And a Help page is probably static (not showing data from any particular table) and so probably under the `static_pages`.